# adding field to objects inside array by their follow position in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to give to the objects inside the array a key that will help me draw them after, the idea is if the array contain 2 (or more) of the same model **in a row** the first object gets `type: 'first'` and the last get `type: 'last'` and whats between them will get `type: 'between'` but if there is some other model between them then I don't to push any key inside.
lets take this array for example

```
const cars = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "z300",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "swift 1",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "swift 2",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "i20",
    model: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Hyundai'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "swift 3",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    },
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "superB",
    model: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Skoda'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "z300",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "swift 30",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "swift 31",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "swift 32",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    }
  }
]
```

in this case I want the array to transform into that

```
const cars = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "z300",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    },
    type: 'first'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "swift 1",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    },
    type: 'between'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "swift 2",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    },
    type: 'last'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "i20",
    model: {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Hyundai'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    name: "swift 3",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    },
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    name: "superB",
    model: {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Skoda'
    }
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    name: "z300",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    },
    type: 'first'
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    name: "swift 30",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    },
    type: 'between'
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    name: "swift 31",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    },
    type: 'between'
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    name: "swift 32",
    model: {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Suzuki'
    },
    type: 'last'
  }
]
```

and if there is in the array only 2 I'd add `type: first` to the first one and `type: last` to the one after.
It's really important that I'll keep the order of the array as it is (as if the same model comes again as a single object (without the same modal after him) he doesn't get a type) but the this situation can be repeated like the same model can be found many times in a row but in different position.

now I can't think about a good way to do it, any ideas directions will more then welcomed :)

thanks!

Comment: how do you access the array currently (can you post a piece of js code)? Also, how does that type:first/between/last keys help you to draw them after?

Comment: @S.Serp, thanks for the reply, hmm I thought making a function that will handle the array and will 'transform' it into my needs. and it will help me with the css (to pass some relevant class names according to the `type` value)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a) to collect the series of object with the same model name/id. Then use reduce again to convert the objects to an array with the types added:

```js
const cars = [{"id":1,"name":"z300","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":2,"name":"swift 1","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":3,"name":"swift 2","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":4,"name":"i20","model":{"id":2,"name":"Hyundai"}},{"id":5,"name":"swift 3","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":6,"name":"superB","model":{"id":3,"name":"Skoda"}},{"id":7,"name":"z300","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":8,"name":"swift 30","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":9,"name":"swift 31","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":10,"name":"swift 32","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}}];

/** generate the the type according to the place in the series **/
const getType = (place, length) => 
  place === 0 ? 'first' : (place === length - 1 ? 'last' : 'between');

const result = cars
  /** reduce to an array of objects that describe a series of models **/ 
 .reduce((c, { model: { id } }, index) => {
  if(!index || id !== c[c.length - 1].id) { // if 1st or the current model name is not equal to the previous start a new series
   c.push({ id, carsIdx: [] }); // a series object
  }

  c[c.length - 1].carsIdx.push(index); // push the the current car index to the last series object

  return c;
 }, [])
  /** reduce the array of series back to an array of cars **/
 .reduce((r, { carsIdx }) => {
  if(carsIdx.length < 2) { // if the number of cars in the series is less than 2, just push the original object according to index
   carsIdx.forEach((idx) => r.push(cars[idx]));
  } else { // if not extend the car object with the type according to his place in the series
   carsIdx.forEach((idx, place, arr) => r.push(Object.assign({
    type: getType(place, arr.length)
   }, cars[idx])));
  }

  return r;
 }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Good. But from performance point of view, this code can be slow for large amount of data as it uses several loops (reduce, forEach ...). Although, it may not be significant most of the time.

Comment: The 1st reduce goes over the array once. The forEach inside the 2nd reduce does exactly what the 2nd for loop in your code do - goes over a sequence, and not the whole array.

Answer (score 2):

One of the most straight forward and easy to understand solution will be using two loops to find beginning and end of each sequence of models (using their model id's) as following:

```js
const cars = [
  { id: 1, name: "z300", model: {id: 1, name: 'Suzuki'} },
  { id: 2, name: "swift 1", model: {id: 1, name: 'Suzuki'} },
  { id: 3, name: "swift 2", model: {id: 1, name: 'Suzuki'} },
  { id: 4, name: "i20", model: {id: 2, name: 'Hyundai'} },
  { id: 5, name: "swift 3", model: {id: 1, name: 'Suzuki'} },
  { id: 6, name: "superB", model: {id: 3, name: 'Skoda'} },
  { id: 7, name: "z300", model: {id: 1, name: 'Suzuki'} },
  { id: 8, name: "swift 30", model: {id: 1, name: 'Suzuki'} },
  { id: 9, name: "swift 31", model: {id: 1, name: 'Suzuki'} },
  { id: 10, name: "swift 32", model: {id: 1, name: 'Suzuki'} }
];


var m, m1;
var n=cars.length;

for(var i=0; i<n; i++) {
    m = cars[i].model.id;
    if(m == m1) { //same model as prev item: new sequence detected
        cars[i-1].type = 'first';
        cars[i].type = 'between';
        for(i=i+1; i<n; i++) {
            m = cars[i].model.id;
            if (m != m1) break; //sequence finished
            cars[i].type = 'between';
        }
        cars[i-1].type = 'last';
    }
    m1 = m;
}

console.log(cars);
```

Comment: Change id: 3 model name to "Hyundai", and see what happens.

Comment: @OriDrori i used model id's to identify models, if you change model name to Hyundai, you should also change its model id to 2. The code seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to check previous, current and next values of the object at the current iteration of array

```js
const cars = [{"id":1,"name":"z300","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":2,"name":"swift 1","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":3,"name":"swift 2","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":4,"name":"i20","model":{"id":2,"name":"Hyundai"}},{"id":5,"name":"swift 3","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":6,"name":"superB","model":{"id":3,"name":"Skoda"}},{"id":7,"name":"z300","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":8,"name":"swift 30","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":9,"name":"swift 31","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}},{"id":10,"name":"swift 32","model":{"id":1,"name":"Suzuki"}}];

const [first, between, last] = ["first", "between", "last"];
for (let [key, car, index = +key] of Object.entries(cars)) {
  const {model: {name: _name}} = car; 
  if (index > 0) {
    let [prev, next] = [cars[index - 1], cars[index +1]];
    if (prev.model.name === _name) {
      if (next && next.model.name === _name 
        && !car.type && !prev.type) {
          [prev.type, car.type, next.type] = types;
       }
       if (prev.type === types[1] 
          && next && next.model.name === _name
          || next && next.model.name === _name) {
            car.type = between;
       }
       if (next && next.model.name !== _name 
          && prev.model.name === car.model.name 
          || !next && prev.model.name === _name) {
            car.type = last;
       }
    } 
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(cars, null, 2));
```